# How to add the special price for every product thrugh excel sheet in magento 2?

Tags: magento2.2.7

I am using Magento 2.2.7 how to add the special price. and it will be showing the mrp and special price for every product how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can import using `sku,store_view_code,attribute_set_code,product_type,special_price` fields in CSV. You can ignore from and to date.

Comment: thank you @Kishan it is working.